# Windows 7 install "Load Driver" error, Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, lenovo-laptop

Can anyone help me to figure out why I cannot get Windows 7 x64 to install on my Lenovo Flex 2-15. I have turned secure boot off, enabled legacy mode so that UEIF don't get in the way. It boots up to the install screen and then the USB drive goes off. I'm using a Sandisk Cruzer 8GB flash drive and then light completely goes off when it hits the install screen. I continue to have the "Load Driver" error and nothing will show up if I even try to browse for this driver. I can't understand what is going on because I can put the flash drive on my desktop pc and it boots up to install fine without this error.

Comment: When you say install screen, you mean where there is the install button" before it trys to detect hard drives?

Comment: I finally got it to install, even though I had turned UEFI off in the BIOS, I also had to tell it to boot legacy devices first. For some reason it wouldn't list the hard drive otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem on my Lenovo Flex 2 15 when trying to install Windows 7 (it's shipped with Windows 8.1)!

In order to boot up on an USB in the first place, you need to push the "Novo button" (in reality a pinhole) on the right side, almost up front. This will show a list of four options; choose "BIOS Setup".

In the BIOS under the tab "Boot":

- Set "Boot mode" to "Legacy support"
- Set "Boot priority" to "Legacy First"

Under the tab "Configuration":

- Set "USB Legacy" to "Enabled"
- Set "xHCI Mode" to "Disabled" (I had to do this in order to avoid a shutdown loop)

Under the tab "Exit":

- Set "OS Optimized Defaults" to "Other OS"

Finally, to be able to proceed beyond the error on "missing driver for CD/DVD/USB" once the setup has initiated, I put the driver for USB (it only exists for Bay Trail-M architectures, but I have a Haswell (i5-U4210) and included it for safe measure), the Intel Chipset Driver and the Intel Management Driver for W7 64-bit in the root of the bootable USB-device (only the Haswell-version of these).

Subsequently I was able to install W7 Pro 64-bit successfully.