# Trying to install Windows 7 from bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, drivers

I am trying to install a fresh copy of Windows 7 x64 from a bootable USB on my Lenovo laptop with Linux currently installed. I get stuck on the setup which claims that it cannot find a "device driver".

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/923439/337631), which I found on this site, seems to address my problem the best and I have tried following its instructions.

I want to know more specifically how it is done:

- Where do I find the specific files of "Intel Chipset Manager"?
- How specifically do I put it in the "root of the bootable USB-device"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 install "Load Driver" error, Lenovo laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/873781/windows-7-install-load-driver-error-lenovo-laptop)

Comment: Because there is missed files in your bootable USB, format your USB and try again, if that doesn't solve your problem try other program to make bootable USB.